# Why the Alamofire return early?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, gaode, parameters: ["location": location,"key":key])
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.response?.statusCode == 200 else{
                return
            }
            js = JSON(response.result.value!)
            guard js["infocode"].string! == "10000" else
            {
                return
            }
            print("JSON: \(js)")
            guard js["regeocode"]["formatted_address"].string != nil else{
                return
            }
            print(js["regeocode"]["formatted_address"].string)
    }
    return js["regeocode"]["formatted_address"].string!
```

the code execute `return js["regeocode"]["formatted_address"].string!` before get response.
why?I want get the JSON before return.
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Because it is asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

The return is outside the response block, so it is being returned totally separately from your network request.